# Query [SQL Server] Agregar campo com valores iguais de uma data mais recente e trazer outros atributos referente essa data

Tags: sql-server

Gostaria de ajudar para montar uma query para agregar os nº de telefone iguais e trazer a data mais recente, além disso trazer outros atributos referente essa data no SQL Server.

Eu montei essa query :

```
SELECT [Telefone], MAX([data_cadastro]), count() FROM blacklist GROUP BY [Telefone] having Count()>0 order by [telefone];
```

Ela agrega os telefones iguais e trás a data mais recente, mas o problema está para recuperar os outros atributos referente ao X numero de telefone da data mais recente.

Tebela original:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Resultado da query:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 0):

Uma forma de fazer o que você quer é usar uma junção da tabela original com o resultado da consulta que você já montou. Algo assim:

```
SELECT a.* 
FROM blacklist a, (SELECT Telefone, MAX(data_cadastro) data_cadastro FROM blacklist GROUP BY Telefone) b
WHERE a.Telefone = b.Telefone
    AND a.data_cadastro = b.data_cadastro;
```